# Dialogbox input passing value of submit from before the ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which has a textbox inside a jquery dialog box. It works fine until I load content using an ajax call after that it submits the value of textbox as the previous value that was submitted before ajax call loaded new content.

After the call has been made no matter what I type in the textbox, it always submits that previous value for that textbox. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for few days but no luck so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#popup").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Popup",
    show: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 150
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 150
    },

    clickOutside: true,
    clickOutsideTrigger: "#btn"
  });

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog("open");
  });
});

$.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
  options: {
    clickOutside: false,
    clickOutsideTrigger: ""
  },
  open: function() {
    var clickOutsideTriggerEl = $(this.options.clickOutsideTrigger);
    var that = this;

    if (this.options.clickOutside) {
      $(document).on("click.ui.dialogClickOutside" + that.eventNamespace, function(event) {
        if ($(event.target).closest($(clickOutsideTriggerEl)).length == 0 && $(event.target).closest($(that.uiDialog)).length == 0) {
          that.close();
        }
      });
    }
    this._super();
  },

  close: function() {
    var that = this;
    $(document).off("click.ui.dialogClickOutside" + that.eventNamespace);
    this._super();
  },
});
```

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="btn>Open Popup</button>
<div id="popup" style="display:none;">
<textarea id="textID" style="resize:none"></textarea></div>
```

Ajax call

```
$('.link').on('click', function (e) {
    var load= $(this).attr('href');
    var $this = $(this);
    if(load == "#open") {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "/page/view/" + $(this).parents("[data-id]").attr("data-id"),
            complete: function (event) {
                $("#content").contents().remove();
                $("#content").append(event.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
    });
```

Comment: try this one  `$("#content").empty();`

Comment: I tried it it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: use this out side  ajax ...

Comment: I tried it no luck, I also tried it on the page that is being loaded via ajax no luck again. It works If I copy the text from textbox in dialog to textbox outside of it. All the textbox outside of the dialog send their value fine. The problem is only with the field in the dialog box

Comment: could you show , screenshot !!

Comment: I can try to explain it to you as much as possible and show you the code but I am not allowed to share the screens :(